# How can I use a for loop in Rmarkdown to export data in the same format for multiple sites?

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown

Edit:
I was able to get part of the outcome I was hoping for using map() with the code below:

```
latitude <- c("-22.1", "-22.2", "-22.3")
longitude <- c("119.1","119.2","119.3")
site_id <- c("YCR-06","YCR-42","YCR-13")
date <- c("1/1/23","1/1/23","1/1/23")
site_dimensions <- c("100 x 25 m","100 x 25 m","50 x 50 m")
SiteRecords <- data.frame(latitude, longitude, site_id, date, site_dimensions)


site_id <- c("YCR-06", "YCR-06", "YCR-06", "YCR-42", "YCR-42", "YCR-42", "YCR-13", "YCR-13")
date <- c("12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022", "13/04/2022","13/04/2022")
taxon <- c("Cyperus sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.", "Melaleuca sp.",
"Eucalyptus sp.","Cyperus sp." ,"Melaleuca sp.", "Cyperus sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.")
coverage <- c("45.0","35.0","12.0","0.1","0.1","0.1","35.0","0.1")
plant_hei <-c("1.0", "18.0", "12.0","0.0","0.4", "0.2", "4.0","2.8")
FloraRecords <- data.frame(site_id, date, taxon, coverage, plant_hei)

SiteOutput <- SiteRecords %>%
dplyr::select(site_id, date, latitude, longitude, site_dimensions)
site_names <- unique(SiteOutput$site_id)

generate_rmarkdown_export <- function(site_name) {# Create a new RMarkdown document
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = "Site_Appendix_Template.Rmd",  # Path to your RMarkdown template
    output_file = paste0("Appendix_", gsub(" ", "_", site_name), ".html"),  # Output filename
    params = list(site = site_name),  # Parameters to pass to the RMarkdown document
  )
}

map(site_names, generate_rmarkdown_export)
```

Which links to the following Rmd template:

````
library(rmarkdown)
library(purrr)
library(jpeg)

latitude <- c("-22.1", "-22.2", "-22.3")
longitude <- c("119.1","119.2","119.3")
site_id <- c("YCR-06","YCR-42","YCR-13")
date <- c("1/1/23","1/1/23","1/1/23")
site_dimensions <- c("100 x 25 m","100 x 25 m","50 x 50 m")
SiteRecords <- data.frame(latitude, longitude, site_id, date, site_dimensions)

site_id <- c("YCR-06", "YCR-06", "YCR-06", "YCR-42", "YCR-42", "YCR-42", "YCR-13", "YCR-13")
date <- c("12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022", "13/04/2022","13/04/2022")
taxon <- c("Cyperus sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.", "Melaleuca sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.","Cyperus sp." ,"Melaleuca sp.", "Cyperus sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.")
coverage <- c("45.0","35.0","12.0","0.1","0.1","0.1","35.0","0.1")
plant_hei <-c("1.0", "18.0", "12.0","0.0","0.4", "0.2", "4.0","2.8")
FloraRecords <- data.frame(site_id, date, taxon, coverage, plant_hei)

SiteOutput <- SiteRecords %>%
dplyr::select(site_id, date, latitude, longitude, site_dimensions) 

site_names <- unique(SiteOutput$site_id)


### **`r site_name`**
site_names <- unique(SiteOutput$site_id)


*insert up to two photos here somewhere... *
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap='', out.width='30%', fig.align='left'}

knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/Emily/Desktop/R_trials/YCR-06.jpg")

#generate_image_url <- function(site_name) {
#  paste0("", gsub(" ", "_", site_name), ".jpg")
#         }

#site_names <- unique(SiteOutput$site_id)

#for (site_name in site_names) {
#  image_url <- generate_image_url(site_name)
#  cat(paste0("![](", image_url, ")\n\n"))
#}

SiteOutput <- SiteRecords %>%
dplyr::filter(site_id %in% site_name) %>%
dplyr::select(site_id, date, latitude, longitude, site_dimensions) %>%
#dplyr::rename("site_id" = "Site", "date" = "Date", "latitude" = "Latitude",
#         "longitude" = "Longitude", "site_dimensions" = "Dimensions") %>% 
  t()

knitr::kable(SiteOutput, format = "html", table.attr = 'style="width:20%"')

FloraRecords <- FloraRecords %>%
  select(site_id, date, taxon, coverage, plant_hei)

FloraRecords$site_id <- as.factor(FloraRecords$site_id)

FloraOutput <- FloraRecords %>%
dplyr::filter(site_id %in% site_name) %>%
  dplyr::select(site_id, taxon, coverage, plant_hei)


knitr::kable(FloraOutput, col.names = c('Site', 'Taxon', 'P1 Cover (%)', 'P1 Height (m)'))
````

I haven't been able get the image loop to work yet (it's either zero photos or all photos!), but will have a look at links in the comments :)

Thanks!

**Original:**
I am trying to create a data summary that formats site photos, site details, and plant records in a consistent way. I can do this for an individual site - the following image is an example of what I'm trying to do:
[image: Example site summary].

However, when I try to create a for loop to export data in the same format for multiple sites, I am struggling to reproduce the results. The below data set creates the tables in the above image.

```
latitude <- c("-22.1", "-22.2", "-22.3")
longitude <- c("119.1","119.2","119.3")
site_id <- c("YCR-06","YCR-42","YCR-13")
date <- c("1/1/23","1/1/23","1/1/23")
site_dimensions <- c("100 x 25 m","100 x 25 m","50 x 50 m")
SiteRecords <- data.frame(latitude, longitude, site_id, date, site_dimensions)

site_id <- c("YCR-06", "YCR-06", "YCR-06", "YCR-42", "YCR-42", "YCR-42", "YCR-13", "YCR-13")
date <- c("12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022","12/04/2022", "13/04/2022","13/04/2022")
taxon <- c("Cyperus sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.", "Melaleuca sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.","Cyperus sp." ,"Melaleuca sp.", "Cyperus sp.", "Eucalyptus sp.")
coverage <- c("45.0","35.0","12.0","0.1","0.1","0.1","35.0","0.1")
plant_hei <-c("1.0", "18.0", "12.0","0.0","0.4", "0.2", "4.0","2.8")
FloraRecords <- data.frame(site_id, date, taxon, coverage, plant_hei)

# Site details
SiteOutput <- SiteRecords %>%
dplyr::filter(site_id %in% "YCR-06") %>%
dplyr::select(site_id, date, latitude, longitude, site_dimensions) %>%
t()
knitr::kable(SiteOutput)

#Plant records
FloraRecords <- FloraRecords %>%
  select(site_id, date, taxon, coverage, plant_hei)

FloraRecords$site_id <- as.factor(FloraRecords$site_id)

FloraOutput <- FloraRecords %>%
dplyr::filter(site_id %in% "YCR-06") %>%
  dplyr::select(site_id, taxon, coverage, plant_hei)

knitr::kable(FloraOutput)
```

I have tried to set up a loop in its own document, that refers back to the template, however, each .html file created gives me the matching tables. When I tried to use a placeholder site name instead of a specific site, the tables didn't work at all. Alternatively, they only the site names with no details.

The loop I thought would reference the above 'template' code:

```
unique_sites <- unique(SiteRecords$site_id)

for (site in unique_sites) {
  temp_rmd <- "Site_Appendix_Basic.Rmd" 
  output_file <- paste0(site, ".html")
  rmd_file <- paste0(site, ".Rmd")
  render(input = temp_rmd, output_file = output_file)
}
```

When I have tried to create the loop within the same .Rmd file, the code appears to work, but the tables shown in R studio are different to the ones produced when I press knit.

```
SiteOutput <- SiteRecords %>%
dplyr::select(site_id, date, latitude, longitude, site_dimensions) 

unique_sites <- unique(SiteOutput$site_id)

for (site in unique_sites) {
  # Filter data for the current site
  site_data <- SiteOutput %>% 
    dplyr::filter(site == site_id) %>% t()
  
  # Generate the report for the current site
  cat("## Site:", site, "\n\n")

  knitr::kable(site_data)

}
```

I am happy to keep searching for similar questions, I just can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.
Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Can you share your Rmd file? You'll most likely need to use the `params` argument in `render()` and in the Rmd file. So you can pass in any info related to each site in order to output the correct info.

Comment: Maybe these links could help... https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html; https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html; https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html

Comment: "the tables shown in R studio aren different to the ones produced when I press knit".  Should "aren" be "are" or "aren't"?

Comment: thanks, that was meant to be "are"